# How To Get Min Date Row if Multiple Rows Have Same Values Except the Created Date?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that contains whenever an email has been open. When a user opens an email multiple times you will have rows that shared the same values except the CREATED_DATE (OPENED_DATE of an email).

**TABLE 1 - OPENED_EMAILS**

| CREATED_DATE | EMAIL_CODE | USER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-5-2022 | E1 | U1 |
| 15-5-2022 | E2 | U2 |
| 17-5-2022 | E2 | U3 |
| 17-5-2022 | E3 | U4 |
| 20-5-2022 | E2 | U3 |
| 22-5-2022 | E3 | U4 |
| 23-5-2022 | E3 | U4 |

I would like to make a query that retrieves only the first time an email has been opened by an user (MIN_CREATED_DATE of an opened email).

Expected result:

**TABLE 2 - FIRST_OPENED_EMAILS**

| CREATED_DATE | EMAIL_CODE | USER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-5-2022 | E1 | U1 |
| 15-5-2022 | E2 | U2 |
| 17-5-2022 | E2 | U3 |
| 17-5-2022 | E3 | U4 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of followings.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', CREATED_DATE))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM opened_email t
 GROUP BY t.EMAIL_CODE, t.USER_ID;
```

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_DATE(
         '%d-%-m-%Y',
         MIN(PARSE_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', CREATED_DATE))
       ) AS CREATED_DATE,
       EMAIL_CODE,
       USER_ID
  FROM opened_email t
 GROUP BY 2, 3;
```

- format string `%-m` will display month without preceding 0.

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(t HAVING MIN PARSE_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', CREATED_DATE)).*
  FROM opened_email t 
 GROUP BY t.EMAIL_CODE, t.USER_ID;
```

```sql
 SELECT * FROM opened_email 
QUALIFY MIN(CREATED_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY EMAIL_CODE, USER_ID) = CREATED_DATE;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity what would be the most efficient one?

Comment: It's highly depends on the data and kind of controversal topic. :), so, you should test it with your real dataset. Anyway 2nd standard approach will show good performance and first one using an array will show relatively poor performance in this case, I guess. just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first time `EMAIL_CODE` E3 **AND** `USER_ID` U4 you will need to do something to link them, I would concatenate them then group by that concatenation

```
Select
CONCAT(EMAIL_CODE,USER_ID) as link
min(CREATED_DATE)
group by link
```